# AJAX Enabled WCF Service fails if Date Property is DateTime.MinValue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf

If a AJAX-Enabled WCF should return an Object with a Date Property which is Nothing a Request to this Service fails.

Test.svc

```vb
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

<ServiceContract(Namespace:="WebApp")>
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class Test

   <OperationContract()>
   <WebGet()>
   Public Function TestOperation() As CompositeType
      Dim obj As New CompositeType
      obj.DateProp = Nothing
      obj.StringProp = "Test"
      Return obj
   End Function

End Class

<DataContract()>
Public Class CompositeType
   <DataMember()>
   Public Property DateProp() As Date
   <DataMember()>
   Public Property StringProp() As String

End Class
```

scripttag on Testform.aspx

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $.getJSON('./Test.svc/TestOperation', function (data) {
         alert(data.d.DateProp);
      });
   });
</script>
```

Web.config (serviceModel section)

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WebApp.TestAspNetAjaxBehavior">
                <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>   
        <service name="WebApp.Test">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebApp.TestAspNetAjaxBehavior"
        binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebApp.Test" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Chrome displays on this call the following error message: "failed to load resource".

Has anyone an explanation/idea for this behaviour and how are you supposed to prevent this problem?

Thanks for your advice ;)

Comment: I am not sure about VB.NET, but in C# the DateTime class cannot be null (except if you make it nullable). Maybe something similar is going here?

Comment: Well. Assigning Nothing / null results in a date which is 1/1/1900 0:0:0. However if i assign DateTime.Now then the request works...

Comment: If you want a date field to be empty (or null as we would say), your field should be nullable. Don't assign some "random" value to it unless it has a real meaning in your context.

Comment: sry correction -> it is 1/1/0001 0:0:0 not 1900 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to assign `Nothing` to a `DateTime` field you should make it nullable:

```
<DataMember()>
Public Property DateProp() As Nullable(Of DateTime)
```

I am not a VB.NET expert but as far as I know the `Date` keyword in VB.NET is an alias to the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) structure (which is not nullable), except that VB.NET must be doing some black voodoo magic to allow you to assign Nothing to it. Except that when the serializer attempts to serialize it into JSON the following exception is thrown:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   WebApp:TestOperationResult. The InnerException message was 'DateTime
>   values that are greater than DateTime.MaxValue or smaller than
>   DateTime.MinValue when converted to UTC cannot be serialized to
>   JSON.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Comment: Shouldn't a date which is not assigned be equal to DateTime.MinValue? (At least `CDate(Nothing).Equals(DateTime.MinValue)` returns True)

Comment: @Nicholas, yes, that's what will happen when you use the `DateTime` type. Try replacing the `Date` alias with `DateTime` in your property and you will see that if you don't assign a value it will be auto assigned to DateTime.MinValue which is the default value.

Comment: Yeah. But in the exception message you quoted there is something about `...smaller than DateTime.MinValue...`. Is this a bug in the JSON Serializer?

Comment: @Nicholas, I don't know if it is a bug in the JSON Serializer. I would be more tempted to say that you are incorrectly using the DateTime field in .NET which is a value type. You are attempting to assign `Nothing` to a value type which in a language such as C# is impossible. I don't know why VB.NET even allows you to write this line.

Comment: I stripped my whole application down to the problem. There I just don't assign the property. However: Assigning `DateTime.MinValue` leads to the same problem. At least, making the Date-Property Nullable solves the problem. Thanks so far :)